# perl error when trying to insert a line at the end of a file

Tags: perl, sed

I have below code in perl file. The intention of this command is to add a line "- - test 0" at the end of file.txt.

```
system(" find  . -type f -name file.txt | xargs sed -i -e "$ a- - test 0" ");
```

When i try to run the script, I'm getting error as shown below.

```
Scalar found where operator expected at timeStampConfig.pl line 24, near "" find  . -type f -name file.txt | xargs sed -i -e "$ a"
    (Missing operator before $ a?)
Number found where operator expected at timeStampConfig.pl line 24, near "test 0"
    (Do you need to predeclare test?)
String found where operator expected at timeStampConfig.pl line 24, near "0" ""
    (Missing operator before " "?)
syntax error at timeStampConfig.pl line 24, near "" find  . -type f -name file.txt | xargs sed -i -e "$ a"
Execution of timeStampConfig.pl aborted due to compilation errors.
```

I tried executing below line from the command prompt and it works fine.

```
find . -type f -name file.txt | xargs sed -i -e '$ a- - test 0'
```

I also tried to use single quotes as shown below but ended up with an error.

```
system("find  . -type f -name file.txt | xargs sed -i -e '$ a- - test 0'");

sed: -e expression #1, char 1: unknown command: `-'
```

I'm new to perl, need some help with this.

Comment: A general comment: can do all that very nicely in Perl, once you are in a Perl program (instead of running a complex shell command out of it)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you want double quotes within a double-quoted string, you need to escape the double-quotes: `"...\"foo\"..."` but in this case you should most probably replace the inner double-quotes with single-quotes:

```perl
system("find  . -type f -name file.txt | xargs sed -i -e '\$ a- - test 0'");
#                                                        ^              ^
#                                                        +---- here ----+
```

Note that the `$` needs to be escaped in the double-quoted string. You could also separate the building of the string to avoid having to escape anything:

```perl
my $expr='$ a- - test 0';
system("find  . -type f -name file.txt | xargs sed -i -e '$expr'");
```

Comment: Hi Ted, thanks for your response. I have tried that already but ended up with below error ```sed: -e expression #1, char 1: unknown command: `-'```

Comment: @RandomGuy Sorry, I forgot to add an escape for `$`  :-) I updated the answer.

Comment: Or use `qq()` operator for outer quotes (`perl -wE'say qq(A "quote")'`), when double quotes are actually needed inside.  But in general I'd really recommend to break that job up and do it in Perl ... but then that's something else...

Comment: @zdim I agree. I was contemplating offering a pure perl alternative but thought that showing solutions to the immediate problem would be more helpful in the long run.

Comment: "_... showing solutions to the immediate problem ..._"  -- absolutely agree, didn't mean to suggest otherwise at all.  In this case that would probably be unwarranted I'd say.  They're asking a very specific and precise question without even a hint of doubts or other approaches.  I think a mere comment is right here.